# how to iterate a complex json structure in groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need to iterate a json file within my jenkins pipeline in order to get some values inside the "fields" value such as "System.AreaPath" for instance , the json file has the following structure:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "AcornAgileProcess.BugSource": "Ad Hoc",
    "AcornAgileProcess.IssueType": "Content",
    "Custom.BuildVariant": "Default",
    "Custom.ReproinRetail": "No",
    "Custom.SQInvestigationStatus": "Not started",
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.GameArea": "Art - technical/FX",
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.GameMode": "In-Game (all)",
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.ReproCount": 4,
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.ReproRate": "5 - Consistently (100%)",
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.ReproTime": 5,
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.SkuTested": "sometext",
    "System.AreaId": 1098,
    "System.AreaLevel1": "sometext",
    "System.AreaPath": "sometext",
    "System.AssignedTo": {
      "_links": {
        "avatar": {
          "href": "someurl"
        }
      },
      "descriptor": "aad.NmE1MWI2NjMtOWU2Ny03NWYyLTlkOGEtNjMwMDFhMzVlZDI3",
      "displayName": "Triage",
      "id": "sometext",
      "imageUrl": "someurl",
      "uniqueName": "sometext",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    "System.AuthorizedAs": {
      "_links": {
        "avatar": {
          "href": "someurl"
        }
      },
      "descriptor": "aad.YmJkMGZjNmItMTBjYi03ODYxLTk0NTAtNGZjNGYwYjkzMmM3",
      "displayName": "sometext",
      "id": "someid",
      "imageUrl": "someurl",
      "uniqueName": "sometext",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    "System.AuthorizedDate": "2021-03-31T23:18:58.513Z",
    "System.ChangedBy": {
      "_links": {
        "avatar": {
          "href": "someurl"
        }
      },
      "descriptor": "aad.YmJkMGZjNmItMTBjYi03ODYxLTk0NTAtNGZjNGYwYjkzMmM3",
      "displayName": "sometext",
      "id": "someid",
      "imageUrl": "someurl",
      "uniqueName": "sometext",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    "System.ChangedDate": "2021-03-31T23:18:58.513Z",
    "System.CommentCount": 0,
    "System.CreatedBy": {
      "_links": {
        "avatar": {
          "href": "someurl"
        }
      },
      "descriptor": "aad.NTcyMTBjZmQtY2VlOC03NjFhLTk4YzctYTc2YjA4NDUyZDU5",
      "displayName": "sometext",
      "id": "someid",
      "imageUrl": "someurl",
      "uniqueName": "sometext",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    "System.CreatedDate": "2021-03-31T23:16:45.42Z",
    "System.Id": 896092,
    "System.IterationId": 1093,
    "System.IterationLevel1": "sometext",
    "System.IterationPath": "sometext",
    "System.NodeName": "sometext",
    "System.PersonId": 31919392,
    "System.Reason": "New",
    "System.Rev": 2,
    "System.RevisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "System.State": "New",
    "System.TeamProject": "sometext",
    "System.Title": "sometext",
    "System.Watermark": 1589040,
    "System.WorkItemType": "Bug"
  },
  "id": 896092,
  "relations": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "isLocked": false,
        "name": "Related"
      },
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Related",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "authorizedDate": "2021-03-31T23:16:45.42Z",
        "id": 12326470,
        "name": "ParticleEffects.mp4",
        "resourceCreatedDate": "2021-03-31T23:09:55.437Z",
        "resourceModifiedDate": "2021-03-31T20:03:35.273Z",
        "resourceSize": 23883076,
        "revisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "rel": "AttachedFile",
      "url": "someurl"
    }
  ],
  "rev": 2,
  "url": "someurl"
}
```

My groovy knowledge is very basic so I tried with these 2 ways:

```
def getTags(){
    def json = readJSON file: "test.json"
    def tags = ""
    def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
    
    slurped.each{ key, value ->
    value.each {k, v ->
       println "${v}"
    }
    }
}
```

with which I get this error `15:30:31  hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (net.sf.json.JSONObject) values: [[fields:[AcornAgileProcess.BugSource:Ad Hoc, AcornAgileProcess.IssueType:Content, ...], ...]]`

```
def getTags(){
    def json = readJSON file: "test.json"
    println json
    def tags = ""
    for (key in json.keySet()) {
        if (key == "System.Tags"){
            tags = json.get(key)
        }
    }
    println tags
}
```

and with these one I do not know how to get deeper inside the fields value to get the ones inside of it

Comment: parseText() is for strings. json should already be a JSONObject, no need to parse again.

Comment: The shortest route would be `data.fields."System.Tags"`. No need to iterate the keyset and look for the key. Yet your example above does not contain a `System.Tags` key, but you code there would work in general (yet inefficient) once you dont' double-parse the json. To go deeper use above dot-syntax to follow the path down.

Comment: thx guys, I will try the second way as all the json I will be getting will have that value for sure so if that works it is an easier way

Comment: I guess it would be something like 'def tags = json.data.fields."System.Tags"'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def json = readJSON file: "test.json"
println json.fields.'System.AreaPath'
```

it's the same as

```
def jsonString = readFile file: "test.json"
def json = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsonString)
println json.fields.'System.AreaPath'
```

JsonSlurperClassic returns serializable maps/arrays - use it to avoid non-serializable exception.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to iterate a json file within my jenkins pipeline in order to
> get some values inside the "fields" value such as "System.AreaPath"
> for instance

You could do this:

```
// get the JSON String from wherever you 
// are getting it, hardcoded here for simplicity
String json = '''
{
  "fields": {
    "AcornAgileProcess.BugSource": "Ad Hoc",
    "AcornAgileProcess.IssueType": "Content",
    "Custom.BuildVariant": "Default",
    "Custom.ReproinRetail": "No",
    "Custom.SQInvestigationStatus": "Not started",
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.GameArea": "Art - technical/FX",
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.GameMode": "In-Game (all)",
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.ReproCount": 4,
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.ReproRate": "5 - Consistently (100%)",
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.ReproTime": 5,
    "PhoenixAgileProcess.SkuTested": "sometext",
    "System.AreaId": 1098,
    "System.AreaLevel1": "sometext",
    "System.AreaPath": "sometext",
    "System.AssignedTo": {
      "_links": {
        "avatar": {
          "href": "someurl"
        }
      },
      "descriptor": "aad.NmE1MWI2NjMtOWU2Ny03NWYyLTlkOGEtNjMwMDFhMzVlZDI3",
      "displayName": "Triage",
      "id": "sometext",
      "imageUrl": "someurl",
      "uniqueName": "sometext",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    "System.AuthorizedAs": {
      "_links": {
        "avatar": {
          "href": "someurl"
        }
      },
      "descriptor": "aad.YmJkMGZjNmItMTBjYi03ODYxLTk0NTAtNGZjNGYwYjkzMmM3",
      "displayName": "sometext",
      "id": "someid",
      "imageUrl": "someurl",
      "uniqueName": "sometext",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    "System.AuthorizedDate": "2021-03-31T23:18:58.513Z",
    "System.ChangedBy": {
      "_links": {
        "avatar": {
          "href": "someurl"
        }
      },
      "descriptor": "aad.YmJkMGZjNmItMTBjYi03ODYxLTk0NTAtNGZjNGYwYjkzMmM3",
      "displayName": "sometext",
      "id": "someid",
      "imageUrl": "someurl",
      "uniqueName": "sometext",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    "System.ChangedDate": "2021-03-31T23:18:58.513Z",
    "System.CommentCount": 0,
    "System.CreatedBy": {
      "_links": {
        "avatar": {
          "href": "someurl"
        }
      },
      "descriptor": "aad.NTcyMTBjZmQtY2VlOC03NjFhLTk4YzctYTc2YjA4NDUyZDU5",
      "displayName": "sometext",
      "id": "someid",
      "imageUrl": "someurl",
      "uniqueName": "sometext",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    "System.CreatedDate": "2021-03-31T23:16:45.42Z",
    "System.Id": 896092,
    "System.IterationId": 1093,
    "System.IterationLevel1": "sometext",
    "System.IterationPath": "sometext",
    "System.NodeName": "sometext",
    "System.PersonId": 31919392,
    "System.Reason": "New",
    "System.Rev": 2,
    "System.RevisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "System.State": "New",
    "System.TeamProject": "sometext",
    "System.Title": "sometext",
    "System.Watermark": 1589040,
    "System.WorkItemType": "Bug"
  },
  "id": 896092,
  "relations": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "isLocked": false,
        "name": "Related"
      },
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Related",
      "url": "someurl"
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "authorizedDate": "2021-03-31T23:16:45.42Z",
        "id": 12326470,
        "name": "ParticleEffects.mp4",
        "resourceCreatedDate": "2021-03-31T23:09:55.437Z",
        "resourceModifiedDate": "2021-03-31T20:03:35.273Z",
        "resourceSize": 23883076,
        "revisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "rel": "AttachedFile",
      "url": "someurl"
    }
  ],
  "rev": 2,
  "url": "someurl"
}
'''

def jsonObject = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def result = jsonObject.fields.'System.AreaPath'
println result
```

That will print `"sometext"`.

Comment: I cannot define the json myself as I would be getting a json from a query, then using .parsetext() would not work

Comment: "I cannot define the json myself as I would be getting a json from a query, then using .parsetext() would not work" - It is not true that you can't use `parseText` if you are getting the json from a query.  You could turn the results of the query into a `String`.  If you specifically want a solution that does not involve parseText you should express that in the question.  Best of luck.